# Differentiating between mouseup mousedown and click

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, dom-events, settimeout

I know that `mousedown` happens when a user depresses the mouse button, `mouseup` happens when the release the mouse and `click` is of course two events `mousedown` and `mouseup.` I have three different events each dealing with these three events mouseup down and click. My question is how to differentiate between the three, now my mouse down has a timer, so I was thinking of adding a boolean in that timer and testing it within the click I tried this and it didn't work to my standards.

`Mousedown`- timer checks for certain classes then if none of these classes exist within the targeted element proceed

`Mouseup`- clear the timer

`Click`- open a module

I may have not made the boolean a global variable that each can read or not, or I am missing something completely. Here is an example quick code of my full code:

```
   var isDown = false;
 ee[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
   if(isDown===false){
     openModule();
    }
  },false);

 ee[i].addEventListener('mousedown',function(){
     var timer;
     var $this = this;
     timer = setTimeout(function(){
    if($this.className == "class"){
     isDown=true;
     createActive();
     }
   },500);
 },true);

  ee[i].addEventListener('mouseup',function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
  },false);
```

That is just a quick example. I may have missed some coding but I hope you catch my drift in the code above. Anyone know of a good way to differentiate between the three events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rewritten your code utilizing jQuery...

```
var isDown = false;
var timer;

$('.class').mousedown(function(){
    isDown = false;
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        isDown = true;
        //createActive();
            console.log('MOUSE DOWN');
    }, 500);
}).mouseup(function(){
    if(isDown === false){
        //openModule();
            console.log('CLICK');
    }else{
            console.log('MOUSE UP');
    }
    clearTimeout(timer);    
});
```

If you simply add jQuery to your page, my code will automatically attach itself to any element in your document with a class of 'class'.

I've commented out your createActive(); and openModule(); calls so that you can play around with it (viewing your javascript console at runtime will show you the script in action - remove the console.log() stuff when you're done playing). This code could be optimised a bit more but it will give you the general idea.

Your timer variable needed to be created globally (I moved it out of the function).

In this case (declaring a mousedown time barrier) the click function will be rendered useless so I've improvised it into the mouseup function.

It's good to know core javascript, but jQuery is just too easy and powerful to ignore.

Comment: Haha, I am not using jQuery hence why I didn't write jQuery as a tag ;)  Also I used to use jQuery alot, though after reviewing a lot of the jQuery library I probably won't use it much. It's ok here and there, also it is a wonderful thing to know how Vanilla works for the code I've written instantiates in like 20ms rather jQuery would be like 1000ms just a fleux number but still. I see what you did so I'll change it to Vanilla and if I get it all fine and dandy I'll add how I created it all.

Comment: Yes, it will be pretty easy to un-jQuery it. Just change "$('.class').mousedown(" back to "ee[i].addEventListener('mousedown'," and do the same basic thing to the mouseup portion. I wrote a jQueryless one but ran into an issue with your class thing (perhaps if I understood your goal a bit better) and didn't want to take any more time figuring it out.
jQuery is just so easy on the coder, and though its runtime speeds might perhaps lack (can't confirm or deny) as long as you're not working with massively complex code that eats the users system to death, the results are far worth it.

Comment: No yeah you are right, the code is very long, and instead of using jQuery I decided to use JavaScript (vanilla) as it was my lightweight option compared to jQuery, It doesn't eat the users system but with jQuery you would have to do a lot of unnecessary things to complete the functionality of the code. Especially with jQuery .each which I despise lol. I'll mark your answer as correct as you are the only one, and it was close enough to me to where I was going besides the jQuery ;)

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to this so I will definitely have to take the posters tags into account from now on.
I stuck to 'vanilla' for so long, but once I started noticing the lightweight coding I could do with jQuery I haven't looked back... Perhaps I will study and compare the delay and electron waste of both sides to weigh in on future ventures. Thanks again and good luck and good coding to you!

Comment: Same here, and yeah when I was new I had a hard time here as well with people so I wasn't goin to downvote you or anything. Good coding to you as well man.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const isDown = ref(false)
const timer = ref(0)

const mouseDown = () => {
  isDown.value = true
  timer.value = setTimeout(() => {
    isDown.value = false
  }, 120)
}

const mouseUp = () => {
  if (isDown.value === true) {
    hideModal()
  } else {
    return
  }
  clearTimeout(timer.value)
}
```